# Which process runs Webmin Scheduled Functions?

Tags: webmin

Exactly who wakes up and runs the entries in Webmin Scheduled Functions? doesn't seem to be crond. is it miniserv.pl?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `miniserv.pl` file, tells me that as *miniserv* is always running, it effectively manages its cron jobs.

```
# Initially read webmin cron functions and last execution times
&read_webmin_crons();
```

Search through the file for `webmin_crons` string, you will get all info you need in this regard.

As far as I'm aware, we don't use system *crond* to run internal scheduled functions.